# Query PHP output suddenly only shows code, no values?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I recently had my eureka moment when I finished my first database connection. After closing my browser and reopening the html form, the output suddenly changed to code instead of the database values?

**HTML form:**

```
<form action="formulier3.php" method="post">
Hoogte: <input type="text" name="height"><br>
Breedte: <input type="text" name="width"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP Page:**

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "addressbook";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE height = " . $_POST["height"] . "  AND width = " . $_POST["width"] . "";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

print $db_field['ID'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['value'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['height'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['width'] . "<BR>";

}

mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}

?>
```

**This is my output:**

```
"; print $db_field['value'] . "
"; print $db_field['height'] . "
"; print $db_field['width'] . "
"; } mysql_close($db_handle); } else { print "Database NOT Found "; mysql_close($db_handle); } ?>
```

Does anyone knows what's going on here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you 100% sure the PHP code above is what's actually in your file? This really looks like you have a stray `?>` or something on the line  `print $db_field['ID'] . "<BR>";`

Comment: Possible BOM character maybe..

Comment: Possible fix: delete the entire line `print $db_field['ID'] . "<BR>";` and try retyping it by hand. If there's a BOM character or similar, that will nuke it.

Comment: Apart from the HTML tags, this is the complete code.. Strange enough it worked (therefore my eureka moment), but when I reopend my browser (to feel euphoric again) it suddenly only showed my the code..?

Comment: See the answer Carlos posted - please confirm whether the page source contains all of your PHP code, or just the portion you quoted under "this is my output" above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow your server has stopped processing your php pages through the php processor (apache module or fastcgi or whatever).

What you see is the effect of presenting your php code as html. The fact that you don't see all your code but rather a small part of it, it is because the part from the first `<` (in `<?php`) until the first `>` (in `print $db_field['ID'] . "<BR>";` is being parsed by the browser as an html tag and so it is not printed. If you look at the page source you'll see the full php code.

So there has been some server-side change that has produced that php files are directly server to the browser instead of parsed by the php engine.

One possible cause, is that you are developing in your local computer and when it worked you typed in your browser something like `http://localhost/your_page.php` but now you are opening the php file directly from the filesystem, so the browser shows something like `file:///xampp/htdocs/your_page.php`. You should always open your php pages through the web server (ie. using `http://localhost/....`) and never by double-clicking on the file in the file explorer.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! This was the solution! Learned a lot today!

Comment: @KevinHamer that was a rather frequent source of frustration for me when I was starting with PHP, so I identified your problem easily after all that experience ;-)